# Проблема с декоратором django permission_required

Tags: python, django, permissions

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой в django==1.8.14, python 2.7:

использую декоратор @permission_required для распределения доступа к страницам. но во всех случаях возвращается ошибка 403, как будто этих прав нет.

Кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите как решить

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required
@permission_required('add_post')
def new_post(request):
      return render(request, 'new.html')
```

Проверял наличие прав внутри вьюхи (без декоратора) таким образом:

```
p = Permission.objects.get(name = 'Can add post')
print p.codename # add_post

print request.user.user_permissions.all() # все права юзера

if request.user.user_permissions.get(codename=p.codename):
   print 'OK'
else:
   print 'NO'
```

Выводило ОК

Answer (score 1):

Следовало добавить название Апликейшена

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required
@permission_required('app.add_post')
def new_post(request):
      return render(request, 'new.html')
```